# How to request a column of an embedded entity TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, where-clause, typeorm

I'm using Nodejs, Typescript, TypeORM, Postgres.

This is about implementing and requesting an embedded entity with TypeORM : https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/embedded-entities

My class got this property with annotation :

```
@Column(() => Periode)
readonly periode: Periode;
```

Which refers to this class :

```
export class Periode implements IPeriode {
  @Column()
  readonly dateDebut: Date;

  @Column()
  readonly dateFin?: Date;
}
```

And I make this request in my repository :

```
async findByDate(date: Date): Promise<Exercice | undefined> {
  const found = await this.model.findOne({
    relations: {
      periode: true,
    },
    where: { periode: { dateDebut: LessThanOrEqual(date), dateFin: MoreThanOrEqual(date) } },
        });

  return found || undefined;
}
```

But when I call "findByDate" I only get this error :

```
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dateDebut')"
```

Do you have an idea of where it comes from ? Thanks in advance for your help !